# How to make action to be called by only the mvc application, Not by direct url request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc-routing, global-asax

In my mvc application I handle 404 and 505 errors by checking response code in Application_EndRequest() method in global.asax.cs and returning custom 404/error page like below

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
            if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                var rd = new RouteData();
                rd.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
                rd.Values["action"] = "PageNotFound";

                IController c = new ErrorsController();
                c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
            }

            else if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 500)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                var rd = new RouteData();
                rd.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
                rd.Values["action"] = "ServerError";

                IController c = new ErrorsController();
                c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have Errors controller like below

```
public ActionResult PageNotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ServerError()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return View("Error");
    }
```

Now when I type the url in addressbar like `http://mydomain/errors/servererror`, It displays my current custom error page

So I want to prevent user by accessing this page, so how can I accomplish that?

P.S.
So far I have tried to solve this by configuring route named "Errors/ServerError" and redirecting it to somewhere else, but I think there may be another good way out there..

Comment: you might try [Authorize].  see herehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413036/override-the-user-isinrole-and-authorizeroles-admin-for-mvc4-application for how he uses roles to refine who is allowed

Comment: It will not work because user can be anyone to see the error and 404 page, I just wanted my action to be called from inside application, not from browser