# I would like to control views based on user role in MVC C#

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to **control views in my action based on user roles**. Roles are stored in database, I have overwritten my `AuthorizeCore` to return true or false based on who is authorized to access the view. I need to know the `userRole` in my controller.

How can I determine the role(s) for the current user?

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index() {

if (userRole = "Admin") { return View("Admin");}
else {return View("Viewer");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your controller extends `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`, then you can access the `User` property on the base class. This will give you an `IPrincipal` instance for the authenticated user, which includes `.IsInRole(string role)`:

```
public ActionResult Index() {

    if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) { return View("Admin");}
    else {return View("Viewer");
}
```

Note: If your configured role provider doesn't automattically support using `.IsInRole`, you can implement your own db lookups using `User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Thank John!  Since the roles are in database, I need to assign(set) the roles before accessing them via User.IsInRole. I want to know how/where to assign the roles.

Comment: @anand What role provider are you using?

Comment: I don;t think I am using any role provider :(

Comment: When you said "Roles are stored in database", what did you mean?

Comment: all the users and roles are defined in the database.

Comment: Ok, so you just need to query the database then.  So you'd need a method that calls into your db with something like `select * from UserRoles where UserName = @UserName` (using the Contoller's `User.Identity.Name` for the username).

Comment: I have a table, that assigns users to roles. 
 
 User Role
 a  Admin
 b  Admin
 c  Viewer
 d  Viewer

Comment: Right I am already doing that in AuthorizeCore. Can I set the role of the user in AuthorizeAttribute and then later access it in controller without querying the DB again.

Comment: In that case, you _could_ add the user's roles to the passed-in `httpContext` object's `Session` key/value store in your `AuthorizeCore` method, then check the values from `this.HttpContext` in your controller.  However, the preferred approach is to create a custom RoleProvider that implements `IsInRole`, which would also allow you to use the default `Authorize` attribute implementation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413036/override-the-user-isinrole-and-authorizeroles-admin-for-mvc4-application

Comment: Thank you that resolved my issue. I did not know about the session object.